# Unexpected error in conditional when using Lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

My team and I are encountering unexpected behavior involving a shared content area, conditional logic, and the `Lookup` function.

```
%%[

var @MID
set @MID = [memberid]

var @StoreClosestNew

if @MID == 1234567 then

    Set @StoreClosestNew = Lookup(
        'MID_1234567_Data_Extension',
        'NEW_STORE_ID',
        'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
        emailaddr
    )

else

    Set @StoreClosestNew = Lookup(
        'MID_9876543_Data_Extension',
        'NEW_STORE_ID',
        'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
        emailaddr
    )

endif

]%%
```

For example, an email template is in MID 9876543 has a Shared Content Area containing the above AMPscript. The conditional should resolve to the `else` statement (and does when debugging with functions other than `Lookup`). However, we are receiving an error of “A Data Extension of this name does not exist: MID_1234567_Data_Extension”. Why would the `Lookup` in the `if` clause be rendering (or attempting to render)?

(We did come up with a workaround solution by moving the `Lookup` outside of the conditional; however, I’d still like to know if the above error is expected behavior or a bug):

```
%%[

var @MID
set @MID = [memberid]

var @LookupDataExtension

if @MID == 1234567 then

    set @LookupDataExtension = 'MID_1234567_Data_Extension'

else

    set @LookupDataExtension = 'MID_9876543_Data_Extension'

endif

var @StoreClosestNew
set @StoreClosestNew = Lookup(
    'MID_1234567_Data_Extension',
    'NEW_STORE_ID',
    'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
    emailaddr
)

]%%
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have a suspicion that the problem is in the context that your shared content block is located - "Shared" always technically means "located on Enterprise level/parent BU", which might be the reason that the code actually does the lookup inside the parent, and not in MID 1234567. 
In the parent, there might truly not be a data extension called MID_1234567_Data_Extension, which would make the error expected behavior.

Comment: Right. However, outside of the conditional, the Data Extension is found and the `Lookup` works just fine. Same Shared Content Area/Enterprise level.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

1) (you probably did this but anyway)

The error is probably in the condition.
Output the value of @mid to doublecheck that the value of @mid is truly what you expect later in the condition before your lookup.

2) When I do this, I always treat the MID from the personalization string "memberid" as a string, maybe that is an issue.

Try to write the condition like this:

`if @MID == "1234567" then`
(comparing it as a string)

Using the string you can also concat the name of the LookupDataExtension and you can save yourself a lot of duplicate code.

Something like:

```
%%[
SET @MID = memberid /*no brackets required aournd memberid to my knowledge, as you are inside an AMPScript definition block */
]%%

debug - MID is: %%=v(@MID)=%%

%%[
if @MID != "1234567" then
   SET @MID = "9876543"
endif
SET @DE = concat("MID_",@MID,"_Data_Extension")
SET @StoreClosestNew = Lookup(
        @DE,
        'NEW_STORE_ID',
        'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
        emailaddr
    )

]%%
```

Hope this helps.